# Swiftmailer sending just one email

Tags: php, forms, webforms, response, swiftmailer

I have a form which sends the forms contents to an email address, but I now also want to send a response to the email address filled in the form, I tried many different things but only one email gets sent either the response to the email address in the form or the form contents to me.

I'm using swiftmailer to send emails.

Any help is much appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is sending multiple emails with switmailer.see this link http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#sending-emails-in-batch. It deals with sending batch mails.